# Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to align my "cards" vertically when viewed from a mobile phone however I cannot seem to get the syntax right. I tried to 'text-align: center;' float:none' among other tries but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated. thank you.

```css
/* Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) */
@media (max-width: 575px) {  
    .card {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
            <img src="img/websume.png" height="240" width="356" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">My "Web-sume" was my first site to include Bootstrap 4. The site is a responsive site, with a feature only available to moblie devises. The site consist of mostly Bootstrap custom layouts.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img src="img/websume_drpdwn.png" height="240" width="356" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">The "Web-sume" has several fixed images as well as a drop down section which includes my address as well as social links. I used the -web kit layouts for the 'Experience' section of the site.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img src="img/websume_exp.png" height="240" width="356" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">As mentioned before, the site, when viewed through a mobile devise has a feature where if a client wants to get in contact with me they do not have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to get my contact information, a 'email' and 'phone' button appears for easy access.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your demo working now?

Comment: I'm beside myself at how simple that was, Michael. Thank you very much, It was right in front of my face the whole time. I have a lot more learning to do. Much appreciated sir!

Comment: No sweat man :) Sometimes all you need is a second set of eyes. That kind of comment is valid in javascript, but not CSS. If you'd like me to submit that as an answer just lemme know.

Comment: Please, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple oversight - it's the CSS comment breaking your `@media` query. You used `// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)` initially, and in CSS, the comment syntax is `/* Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) */`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, your cards are going off the edge of the screen. This is due to the fact that while you're setting the width of `.card` to 100% for mobiles, you're hard-coding in the widths of the images, and not actually forcing the images to be contained within the bounds of their respective `.card` containers.

The best way to correct this is to specify a max width for all images:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Note that you'll probably also want to set `height: auto`, to make sure that the images don't get squashed:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {  
    img {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7gs4vshy/1/).

Hope this helps! :)